# php mailer con cuenta de gmail no me funciona al volver de un cambio de hosting

Tags: email, phpmailer, gmail

acabo de cambiar de un hosting web a uno anterior porque el nuevo me daba errores , sin embargo, cuando nuevamente trato de enviar correos en el hosting anterior usando phpmailer no me envia correos, sin embargo, en el nuevo, con errores los envia.
¿tengo que esperar algun tiempo para que luego de borrar los datos de esa pagina pueda enviar nuevamente correos usando el hosting anterior?

Comment: Hola. Envía tu correo con errores ¿De que errores hablas? ¿En que se diferencia un hosting de otro? ¿Por que no envía el correo? ¿Sale algún error? Si no eres un poco más concreto con el problema que estás teniendo es difícil poder ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Mira no se entiende mucho lo q necesitas y menos sin codigo y print de errores, si lo que queres ver es q error tenes yo lo que hago es crear un archivo php que mande el mail  con un $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  y lo ejecuto desde un bat que tenga un pause al final asi veo por consola todo el detalle del proceso del envio del mail y puedo ver si es algun error o me bloquearon los puertos, etc, ojo, tal vez hay 10.000 formas mas simples, yo en mi basico conocimiento encontre esa

Comment: te explico @Juan yo en un hosting (el viejo) use phpmailer para mandar correos (sin problemas) cambio a otro hosting para obtener otro dominio gratis y funciona el envio pero mostrando errores de variables,yo molesto, regreso al anterior donde no me mostraban los errores y¿ que sucedió? la página no me mandaba correos como lo hacia antes, pero , el el nuevo si funcionaba, y era el mismo código!!!
creo que era cuestion del hosting anterior , saludos

Comment: errores de variable @Ferni , cosa rara. 
pero el correo volvio a enviarse desde el hosting nuevo , creo que era una cuestion de hosting...